# How to validate empty fields without plugin

Tags: jquery, html

I have the fellowing code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateEmail(email) { 
var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
return re.test(email);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#enviar").click(function() {



var nome = $.trim($("input#nome").val());
if (nome == "") {
$("#nome").focus();
$("#nome").css("background-color","#802c2c");
return false;
}
var email = $.trim($("input#email").val());
if (email == "") {
$("#email").focus();
$("#email").css("background-color","#802c2c");
return false;
}
if (!validateEmail(email)) {
$("#email").focus();
$("#email").css("background-color","#802c2c");
return false;
}
var telefone = $.trim($("#telefone").val());
if (telefone == "") {
$("#telefone").focus();
$("#telefone").css("background-color","#802c2c");
return false;
}
var mensagem = $.trim($("#mensagem").val());
if (mensagem == "") {
$("#mensagem").focus();
$("#mensagem").css("background-color","#802c2c");
return false;
}
});

$('input').keypress(function() { $(this).css("background-color","#17120d") });
$('textarea').keypress(function() { $(this).css("background-color","#17120d") });

});
$(function () {
"use strict";
$('form').on('submit', function (e) {
 e.preventDefault();
$('#unload').fadeOut(2000);
$('#loading').delay(2000).fadeIn(900);
$("#loadresult").hide().delay(2000).fadeIn(900);

    $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'mailer/sendmail.php',
            data: $('#inner-contact').serialize(),
            success: function (html) {
            $("#loadresult").fadeOut(1000);;
            $("#postresult").delay(1000).fadeIn(2000);
            $("#another").hide(1009).delay(2000).fadeIn(2200);
            }
          });

});

   $('#another').click(function() {

    $("#another").hide(100).fadeOut(2000);
    $('#loading').fadeOut(2000);
    $("#postresult").fadeOut(2000);
    $("#unload").delay(2400).show(200); 
   });

});
</script>
```

But with this code i can only validate one field at a time. How can I check all fields at once? As the code is, it validates field by field, that is, when I click on the "send" button it checks the first field, then the second, then the third, and so on. But I need it to check all the fields at once, applying the background color to all those fields that are empty.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/pmt43cg1/ may help

Comment: `return false` will stop the execution of the function, thus only one validation will be performed. @Mohamed-Yousef's comment is an efficient way to validate blank fields.

Comment: Ow, thank's @Mohamed-Yousef ! But how can I use this code along with the function to validate the email. I need the form to be submitted only if the fields are filled and also the email field valued with the above function.

Comment: this is how to check the email give it an id and check for validation https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/pmt43cg1/1/  .. and this is another way by using `.each()` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758259/looping-through-input-fields-for-validation-using-jquery-each

Comment: Thank's man. Nice code.