# Get all the names of input fields inside a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 100 input type text, which are placed in a table.
They have no id attribute.
But they have  unique name attribute.
I want to find the names of all the textboxes and save in an array so that i can use them further.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question does not show any sign of effort

Comment: [How to get name of input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513809/get-attribute-name-value-of-input) + [Looping through all inputs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758259/looping-through-input-fields-for-validation-using-jquery-each) should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with **[`Array#each`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjlsOL5_MPTAhXEN48KHXf0BmIQFggiMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fjquery.each%2F&usg=AFQjCNGWEhQCCVLtjc4aKUDQ621LSgRg_w&sig2=SQ7F8d6YLlj0Unf3v0ua2Q)** and **[`attr('name')`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwitzNqO_cPTAhVMo48KHZZ0DfsQFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fjquery%2Fhtml_attr.asp&usg=AFQjCNHzigUAFN8hkP1Z_m3LHMQexQFpeg&sig2=t4-mQe9bJBzCAo6ydEvzKA)** using jquery and for `text` match only using `input:text`

```js
var a=[];
$('input:text').each(function(){
a.push($(this).attr('name'))
})
console.log(a)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="one" ><input type="text" name="two" ><input type="text" name="three" ><input type="text" name="four" ><input type="text" name="five" ><input type="text" name="six" >
```

Comment: Shoud we really answer such questions that do not show any effort?

Comment: OP should better use `$(":text")` if there're more than just those 100 inputs in table

Answer (score 1):

Loop over `inputs` and use `.each()` function to iterate over each item, then get the names via `.prop()` function.

```js
var names = [];

$('input').each((k,v) => names.push($(v).prop('name')));

console.log(names);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="a">
<input name="b">
<input name="c">
<input name="d">
```

Comment: Shoud we really answer such questions that do not show any effort?

Comment: @Rajesh This is a difficult question. It depends on the content of the question.

Comment: May be its difficult, but still you **have** to share something. Even Google search links would help. But this is just a wish and not a problem. Also if you break your problem, it becomes simple

Answer (score 1):

use this code to get all inputs

html file :

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input name="input1" /></td>
  <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name="input2" /></td>
  <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input name="input3" /></td>
  <td>test</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button id="button">
submit
</button>
<div id="result">
</div>
```

JS :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#button').click(function(){
  var data = []
    $('input').each(function() {
        data.push({
        "name": $(this).attr('name'),
        "value": $(this).val()
        })
    });
    console.log(data)
    $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(data))
  });
});
```

[https://jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/bdj45tva/3/)